# Preparing XML data for Apriori algorithm

Tags: xml, algorithm, mapping, apriori

Generally, Apriori algorithm receives input in form of matrix, as in follows:

```
TID A B C D E
T1 1 1 1 0 0
T2 1 1 1 1 1
T3 1 0 1 1 0
T4 1 0 1 1 1
T5 1 1 1 1 0
```

While, my input is XML data in general form of :

```
 <article key="tr/gte/TR-0263-08-94-165">
<author>Frank Manola</author>
<title>An Evaluation of Object-Oriented DBMS Developments: 1994 Edition.</title>
<journal>GTE Laboratories Incorporated</journal>
<volume>TR-0263-08-94-165</volume>
<month>August</month>
<year>1994</year>
</article>
```

How I could convert such data to a suitable form to be acceptable by the algorithm? Any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python, it would be best to use the Element Tree XML parser (documentation included below). This allows you to parse XML data into a python dictionary that you can then translate however you need. Note, if your XML data files are extremely large, it can be handy to use the iterparse to avoid massive memory requirements.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, what about Java or C#? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not too experienced with them, but for C++ [http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/] and for Java [http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/]